# Absolute positionning in non-relative container

Tags: html, css, gwt

I need to create a modal box into a div container; so it doesn't occupy the whole page, but only it's container. 
The problem is that I need to use Absolute positioning, and this one works properly only if the container have Relative positioning. But I can't modify the positionning of the container (it's up to the user, I'm actually working on a framework). Hope I  was clear, any suggestion?

/* CODE /*

```
.popUp {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: gray;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:0.5;
    position: absolute; //The container of the popUp must be relative and that's the problem
    z-index: 100;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

PopUp will be a FlowPanel I want to add to another Panel, for the popUp component I have a method like this:

```
public void asignParent(Panel parent) {  
  parent.add(this);     
  parent.addStyleName(instance.testCss().relativeContainer());/*this is what I must avoid*/
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code...

Comment: Can you provide some code for us? So we can help you better.

Comment: added, sorry I'm new to the site's editor